# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: alta

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting the following error when trying to update the triggers for a script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/autMe.png)

My script is linked to various form. When filling them, it sends an answer email.
The script stopped working a week ago. It happens to me in the past, and the issue was solved by updating the triggers. This time, when trying to update the triggers I am facing the error message in the screenshot above "An error has occurred. Try to reload the page and try it again".
I have the correct permission on the form, and the script.
As the issue seems to be temporary, I have tried to clean cache and cookie, and also tried to update the triggers in incognito mode, in another browser, and from another account with the necessary permission. The error message remains, and is always the same.

How can stop getting this error message?

Comment: This just sounds like an internal error on Google's side, there's not really anything you can do aside from wait. Apps Script UI pages are notoriously buggy from time to time, if you're still encountering the issue after a few days then you should file an issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Can you translate the error to English

Comment: Errors should be included as text, not as images.